# DRI_PRIME not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, gpu-driver

Platform: Ubuntu 22.04 (installed yesterday)

Problem: Running most programs with `DRI_PRIME=1` doesn't work. I first discovered it when trying to run Minecraft (MultiMC) because it wouldn't use the discrete GPU. I tried using `env DRI_PRIME=1` but it doesn't change anything.
I tried running `glxinfo | grep Device` to see if it's only a game-related problem:

```
okonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ glxinfo | grep Device
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2) (0x9bc4)
rokonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep Device
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2) (0x9bc4)
rokonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep Device
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2) (0x9bc4)
```

Apparently no, and there's an error when trying to launch it with the discrete gpu.
I finally tried `glxgears` and weirdly enough it's working:

```
rokonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
605 frames in 5.0 seconds = 120.873 FPS
rokonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
640 frames in 5.0 seconds = 127.938 FPS
rokonio@rokonio-Dell-G15-5510:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
40009 frames in 5.0 seconds = 8001.736 FPS
```

Addendum: The graphic card I have is a TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (running `lshw -C display`). I have installed ubuntu 22.04 yesterday and didn't change any graphic drivers, but when I go to Additional drivers, it says "Continue using a manually installed driver" and I can't select any different one.

Comment: `DRI_PRIME` doesn't work with Nvidia.

Comment: So what should i use instead ?

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers. But I am not sure how it works with Wayland. Maybe it is better to switch to X11.

Comment: I've installed the drivers and I'm already on X11, rebooted my computer it still doesn't use the gpu

Comment: Please add output of `prime-select query` to your question. And also output of  `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia drivers... via a .deb file... or via Additional Drivers? Show me what Additional Drivers looks like. And `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @Pilot6
```$ prime-select query
nvidia
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
 DeviceName: Onboard - Video
 Subsystem: Dell CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Dell TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: @heynnema I used the command `ubuntu-drivers install` and now the drivers shows correctly on Additional drivers (nvidia-drivers-510) 
I finally found a solution to my problem, I needed to run the command wrapped with `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia` to enable the graphic card on Minecraft or other

Comment: Please add information to your question, not to the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It now works, I needed to install drivers with `ubuntu-drivers install` and then instead of using `DRI_PRIME=1`, use `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`

Comment: Thank you for this! I found I had an application called with all three env variables: `__NV_PRIME...`, `__GLX...`, and `DRI...`. Does that make any difference? is the last just neglected?

Answer (score 0):

Install Nvidia proprietary drivers by

```
ubuntu-drivers install
```

Then you will be able to switch graphics using `prime-select` or GUI Nvidia application.